# Laravel many-to-many relationship insert

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I'm developing a site for medical devices using Laravel
i have a table for the devices and devices categories and users
i have a page that view all the devices that belong to one category
and i make a many-to-many relationship between the devices and user and i made a middle table 
i made the many-to-many relationship in each model (users-devices)

```
 public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(App\User, 'devices_users_relationship' , 'devices_id ', 'user_id');
}
```

now i want to make a button behind every device and when the user click on this button the device stored to his devices (the middle device)

how can i do so??

Comment: We are going to need to see your table definitions. Also many-many relationships should be converted to 2 many-to-1 relationships with an intermediate table.

Comment: Exactly! @bassxzero

Comment: i have an intermediate table which i called it (devices_users_relationship) and it hase three column id , device_id  and user_id  my qusetion is that how can i insert  using these three table and eloquent model?? Thanks@bassxzero

Answer (score 0):

I assume that user is already logged in. So, when he clicks on the device button:

```
auth()->user()->devices()->attach($deviceId);
```